# Search for items in a specific order in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Trying to learn how to search for "pattern-like" sequences in a list in Python, i.e. find whether there is a specific sequence of integers in a list.

My best idea was to check if a) all three numbers are present b) to see if their indices are sequentially greater than each other. But I am getting unexcepted output like so:

```
necessary_sequence = [20, 56, 2]

first_num = necessary_sequence[0]
second_num = necessary_sequence[1]
third_num = necessary_sequence[2]
test_list = [43, 12, 20, 20, 56, 56, 2, 4, 98, 20] #should print output_2, but printing output_1 (order rule is not observed)  

if first_num in test_list and second_num in test_list and third_num in test_list:
    if test_list.index(first_num) < test_list.index(second_num) < test_list.index(third_num):
        print("output_1: all three numbers are in the list in order")
    else:
        print("output_2: the numbers are either missing from the list or are not in order")
```

Can someone pinpoint the flaws in the logic of the above code?

Comment: you are only checking if indexes are greater, but not if indexes are following

Comment: Why do you expect to see output_2? The numbers 20, 56, and 2 appear in that order in your list, so it prints output_1. Please explain in detail what you're trying to do. Assuming `necessary_sequence = [1, 2, 3]`, what would be the expected output for the inputs `[1, 2, 3]`, `[1, 2, 0, 3]` and `[3, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Thanks folks, so only if numbers are in the list as [1, 2, 3] should the output print yes. For example, [1, 2, 2, 3] should print output_2 because 2 occurs twice and thus should break the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected. It just tests if values of the indexes are less than each other. It doesn't check if they are directly beside each other in the list:

```
>>> first, second, third = (20, 56, 2)                                          
>>> test_list = [43, 12, 20, 20, 56, 56, 2, 4, 98, 20]
>>> if all([x in test_list for x in [first, second, third]]):
...    if test_list.index(first) < test_list.index(second) < test_list.index(third):
...        print('output1')                                                        
...    else:
...        print('output2')
... 
output1
>>> print(test_list.index(first))
2
>>> print(test_list.index(second))
4
>>> print(test_list.index(third))
6
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe too advanced, but its hard to resist a 'one liner' comprehension...

```
ns = [20, 56, 2]
tl = [43, 12, 20, 20, 56, 56, 2, 4, 98, 20]

[sum(a == b for a, b in zip(ns, tl[i:])) for i in range(len(tl)-len(ns)+1)]

Out[31]: [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

the pattern is loosely speaking 'convolution': sliding a 'kernal' `ns` incrementally in parallel over another list `tl`, doing some operation between the matching position values, summing the result and collecting the sums at each increment in a list

`for i in range(len(tl)-len(ns)+1)` generates the index `i`

`a == b for a, b in zip(ns, tl[i:])` is a generator expression inside `sum()`

`zip(ns, tl[i:])` lines up `ns` in parallel with the same length slice of `tl` starting at index `i`

`zip` automatically discards the ecxcess `tl` elements

we can `sum` the boolean result from `a == b` becuse of 'duck typing' which turns `True`, `False` into `1`, `0`

the output `[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]` is a list of the number of matches between `ns`  and `tl[i:]` at each `i` for the `i` in `range(len(tl)-len(ns)+1)` where `ns`  and `t1` fully overlap

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is too advanced for me right now, but I will revisit as soon as I master list comprehension better!